# Is google survey with published analytics publicly searchable?

Tags: google-sheets, search-engine

I want to share some google survey results with someone and one way to do it is to use the publish analytics button in generating and sharing results through a url. But is it a publicly searchable url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making your survey public, anyone with the link to your survey can access your survey results. Your survey may be listed publicly and will be searchable on Google or other search engines. You can send the link to others via email or share it on social media.